# Expand/collapse box like Google Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I got this:

```
   <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="visibleContent">
        </div>
        <div class="expandibleContent">
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="visibleContent">
        </div>
        <div class="expandibleContent">
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="visibleContent">
        </div>
        <div class="expandibleContent">
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="visibleContent">
        </div>
        <div class="expandibleContent">
        </div>
   </div>
```

I want `.visibleContent` to be clickable to expand the `.exandibleContent` like Google Images with triangle pointer.

Correct Example: [LINK](https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/EabNrX)

I'm trying to deeply understand that code but I can't.
Can you write a code with the same functionality but only with four images?

I only need a grid of 4 images with the same **slidetoggle** function.

Comment: You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/owbebY
change

```
$('.image-grid').empty().html(cells(50));
```

to

```
$('.image-grid').empty().html(cells(4));
```

do you need like this

Comment: Thanks a lot, number of images is solved. But I don't know how to replace those 4 images

Comment: Change src to your desired url , and if this answer solved your problem then accept it and also upvote

Comment: Answer isn't solved because I don't have a url with my 4 images. I want to insert my images localy once at time.

Comment: Use jquery to append at runtime